# when to resize a hash table?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

In various hash table implementations, I have seen "magic numbers" for when a mutable hash table should resize (grow).  Usually this number is somewhere between 65% to 80% of the values added per allocated slots.  I am assuming the trade off is that a higher number will give the potential for more collisions and a lower number less at the expense of using more memory.

**My question is how is this number arrived at?**

Is it arbitrary? based on testing? based on some other logic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a guess, most people at least *start* from the numbers in a book (e.g., Knuth, Volume 3), which were produced by testing. Depending on the situation, some may carry out testing afterwards, and make adjustments accordingly -- but from what I've seen, these are probably in the minority.

As I outlined in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603712/when-should-i-do-rehashing-of-entire-hash-table/1604428#1604428), the "right" number also depends heavily on how you resolve collisions. For better or worse, this fact seems to be widely ignored -- people frequently don't pick numbers that are particularly appropriate for the collision resolution they use.

OTOH, the other point I found in my testing is that it only rarely makes a whole lot of difference. You can pick numbers across a fairly broad range and get pretty similar overall speed. The main thing is to be careful to avoid pushing the number too high, especially if you're using something like linear probing for collision resolution.

Answer (score 6):

I think you don't want to consider "how full" the table is (how many "buckets" out of total buckets have values) but rather the number of collisions it might take to find a spot for a new item.

I read some compiler book years ago (can't remember title or authors) that suggested just using linked lists until you have more than 10 to 12 items.  That would seem to support more than 10 collisions means time to re-size.

[The Design and Implementation of Dynamic. Hashing for Sets and Tables in Icon](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.5908) suggests that an average hash chain length of 5 (in that algorithm, the average number of collisions) is enough to trigger a rehash.  Seems supported by testing, but I'm not sure I'm reading the paper correctly.

It looks like the resize condition is mainly the result of testing.

Comment: How would resizing decrease number of collisions? The hash function for the longer array will still be the same so collisions will still happen for the same key, right?

Comment: @Core_Dumped - yes, hash function stays the same, and hash value of items in table stay the same. But the length of the buckets changes, and therefore in which bucket items reside. To resize means to change the length of the array (usually) of buckets, then re-bucket all the items in the hash table. Per-bucket chain length goes down on average, which means fewer collisions.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the keys. If you know that your hash function is perfect for all possible keys (for example, using [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)), then you know that you'll have only few collisions, so the number is higher.

But most of the time, you don't know much about the keys except that they are text. In this case, you have to guess since you don't even have test data to figure out in advance how your hash function is behaving.

So you hope for the best. If you hash function is very bad for the keys, then you will have a lot of collisions and the point of growth will never be reached. In this case, the chosen figure is irrelevant.

If your hash function is adequate, then it should create only a few collisions (less than 50%), so a number between 65% and 80% seems reasonable.

That said: Unless your hash table must be perfect (= huge size or lots of accesses), don't bother. If you have, say, ten elements, considering these issues is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the number is a heuristic based on empirical testing.

With a reasonably good distribution of hash values it seems that the magic load factor is -- as you say -- usually around 70%. A smaller load factor means that you're wasting space for no real benefit; a higher load factor means that you'll use less space but spend more time dealing with hash collisions.

(Of course, if you know that your hash values are perfectly distributed then your load factor can be 100% and you'll still have no wasted space and no hash collisions.)

Answer (score 1):

Collisions depend highly on data and used hash function.

Most of numbers based on heuristics or on assumption about normal distribution of hash values. (AFAIK values about 70% are typical for extendible hash tables, but one can always construct such data stream, that you get much more/less collisions)